# Adding uax_url_email analyzer to Elasticsearch 2.4.5

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

I'm trying to add an **analyzer** that uses the `uax_url_email` tokenizer.

```
▶ elasticsearch --version
Version: 2.4.5, Build: c849dd1/2017-04-24T16:18:17Z, JVM: 1.8.0_131

curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/timeline -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "email_analyzer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "uax_url_email"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

However this complains that the index already exists.

```
{
    "error": {
        "index": "timeline",
        "reason": "already exists",
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "index": "timeline",
                "reason": "already exists",
                "type": "index_already_exists_exception"
            }
        ],
        "type": "index_already_exists_exception"
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

So I tried doing an update via `PATCH`

```
curl -XPATCH http://localhost:9200/timeline -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "email_analyzer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "uax_url_email"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

This doesn't complain about any issues, returns no errors and the returned output is the same as if I'd issued a `GET` request to the `/timeline` index

The interesting part of the output is that the settings haven't updated.

```
    "settings": {
        "index": {
            "creation_date": "1497609042039",
            "number_of_replicas": "1",
            "number_of_shards": "5",
            "uuid": "XaRS0KN1SLWcBsl6eLMZcg",
            "version": {
                "created": "2040599"
            }
        }
    },
```

I perhaps wrongly would expect the newly `PATCHED` *analysis* object to be present...

Not sure where I'm going wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first close the index and then open it again:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/timeline/_close'

curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/timeline/_settings' -d '{
  "analysis" : {
    "analyzer":{
      "email_analyzer":{
        "type":"custom",
        "tokenizer":"uax_url_email"
      }
    }
  }
}'

curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/timeline/_open'
```